# Can stucco be applied over smooth sheen paint?

Tags: stucco

I would like to apply a coat of stucco over some smooth sheen (semi-gloss?) paint? Can I expect the stucco to stick to it or does the paint need to be removed or primed with something?

Comment: This is a product-specific question--specific paint, specific stucco product, specific substrate. We can't say with any confidence. Ask your salesperson or the manufacturer.